# Дискриминантный анализ с опцией "Пошаговое включение/исключение" как в Statistika 10?

Tags: r

В Statistica 10 есть возможность сделать дискриминантный анализ с опцией "Пошаговое включение/исключение" ("Forward/Backward stepwise"). Как можно в R сделать такой анализ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Используйте функцию
`MASS::stepAIC()`